# Prevent XSS in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, xss

I know this was asked before, but I am trying to figure out how to prevent XSS attacks for my Spring MVC web application.

1) I added the following to my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

2) Should I also be using Commons StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml() for each property in the form command object before I save it in the database?  Would I need to unescape at some point as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I decided to sanitize my data and remove any HTML tags to avoid JavaScript attacks.

I'm using Jsoup api to do that.

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

Answer (score 2):

Even though escaping html by default stops XSS in many contexts there are certainly contexts where it doesn't work. See an example here:
http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?id=124
I recommend you take a look at the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet. It explains when you need to use different escapings.
Regarding 2 don't escape before putting it in the db. The escape routine could have errors and you can't be sure that the data will be used in the same context every time

Answer (score 2):

I prefer you try the HDIV api for this kind of data security on your application. It prevents this and other 7 different possible attacks on your web application. I am also currently exploring the same API to use with Spring Framework.

[Click here for HDIV home page.](http://hdiv.org/)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This seems very heavy for what I am trying to do.  I just want a simple way to escape malicious characters and then unescape them when I present them in the view.

Comment: You are right. But if you want to make your web application fully secured with other attacks, then must go with something like HDIV. It will surely affect by 2-3% to your performance but its acceptable.

Comment: I disagree. Using a WAF is a valuable layer of defence but is still not an excuse to create vulnerable applications and does not make you "fully secure" by any means.